# Is there anyway in PHP to use uniquely identify a user's router?

Tags: php, unique, router

Is there anyway in PHP to use uniquely identify a user's router? I'd like t know what users are on the same router.

Comment: What do you mean by "the second router"?

Comment: no there isn't any way to make sure , how about if he used proxy , anonymous website surfing ... etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve the users IP address using `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` and then use a `traceroute` utility to get the hops and check for the routers that you wish to find, if you know the IPs of both of them.

***Assuming that the router is not address-translating for them, otherwise this will not work, as it relies on being able to get back through the router to the user.  If either router can return to the user, then it will not work at all. Good for dial-in users though.***

```
<?php
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$router1IP = "123.123.123.123";

$output = array();
exec('traceroute -n ' . $ip, $output, $result);

if ($result == 0) {
    $outputText = implode("\n", $output);
    if (preg_match("/" . preg_quote($router1IP) . "/", $output)) {
        echo "Router 1";
    } else {
        echo "Router 2";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: There's no guarantee that the return path will be the same as the path you take in that direction, so this is a guess at best.  It also depends on whether `REMOTE_ADDR` takes into account the existence of an `X-FORWARDED-FOR` header.

Comment: @Nick Bastin: Quite right, it is a guess - but compared to "no idea" stands some chance of guessing.  It would work for dial-in users.  I have updated my answer to state that.

Answer (score 4):

The general answer is going to basically be no - detecting network topology is a non-trivial operation (and certainly detecting the path packets took to you can be well-nigh impossible from an endpoint).  However, it sounds like you have some kind of specific topology which perhaps if you tell us more about we might be able to help you with.

Presuming the following things:

- You have two ingress routers
- Your web server only has one ethernet interface
- You're trying to determine which router the traffic came through

You could VLAN tag all incoming traffic at each ingress interface (and put all your hosts on untagged switch interfaces), and give yourself an interface alias on your web server for each VLAN, and thus by knowing which virtual interface you came in on, you'll know what ingress router the traffic came from.

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do is identify a users IP address using the `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`.  If ip address corresponds to router, you're in luck.